# как скрыть окно ошибки Winrar в Java

Tags: java, консоль, winrar

Есть класс Java, который распаковывает архивы в каталоге. Если архив поврежден, то открывается окно winrar с содержимым "Архив поврежден или имеет неизвестный формат". Типы архивов zip, rar, arj, 7z.

Подскажите как можно скрыть всплывающее окно? Ниже фрагмент из кода,

```
String command = "C:/Program Files/WinRAR/winrar.exe x -ierr -ibck \"" + dir + file.getName() + "\"  \"" + dir + "." + file.getName() + "/\"";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec(command);
try {
    p.wait();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // если архив поврежден, то приходит сюда
    System.out.println("oshibka");

} 
finally {
    p.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Запуская сторннюю программу с помощью Java у экземпляров класса ```Runtime, Process```, нет средств контроля за её всплывающими окнами и прочим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У программы `winrar.exe` есть ключи командрой строки:

Ключ ***-inul***

*Не выводить сообщения об ошибках*

*решение вопроса.*